# I can't show the results of search in my movies library app doing by reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I try to build a movies library with react js
I take the data from an API, and add Search component
when I type a text in the search bar I have an error,
no results appeared! and there is an error in the console!

```
 isAxiosError.js:10 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://react- 
 japox3.stackblitz.io/' was loaded over 
HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 
'http://www.omdbapi.com/? 
 i=tt3896198&apikey=b0cdc816&s=g'. This request has been blocked; the content 
must be served over 
HTTPS.

isAxiosError.js:10 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
at e.exports (isAxiosError.js:10)
at XMLHttpRequest.l.onerror (isAxiosError.js:10)
```

can you help me to solve it?

this is the code and you can try it
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-japox3?file=src%2FApp.js

Comment: Is there some reason you can't use https for that api call? It works fine for me... other than it returns an error for too many search results?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your site is secure `HTTPS` whereas you are requesting from the omdbapi which is insecure `HTTP`

I would suggest you to use some secure API for the purpose over HTTPS.

Or you could do it without a API too.

Here is a module called [moovies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moovies) that might help.

With this you can setup a local api server just with one line of code.

```
const moovies = require('moovies')
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
app.use('/apipath', moovies.mooviesBackend)
app.listen(8000, () => {
    console.log("Server is listening on port 8000");
})
```

You can also use the methods `moovies.getPlot('tt3896198', callback)` or `moovies.getCast('tt3896198', callback)` to get the same json responses directly from the code without any api.

The callback should be like:

```
function callback(response, error){
    //do your stuff here
}
```

This library is being updated regularly and new features are getting added.

---

Disclosure:  I am the developer of the Library.